# Call a function when tab selected in material design light

Tags: javascript, material-design-lite

I have three tabs on the page.

```
<!-- Tabs -->
<div class="mdl-layout__tab-bar">
  <a href="#plots-tab" class="mdl-layout__tab is-active"">Plots</a>
  <a href="#plots-data-tab" class="mdl-layout__tab">Plots data</a>
  <a href="#report-tab" class="mdl-layout__tab">Report</a>
</div>
```

I need to re-draw plots when Plots tab is selected. I've tried to `onclick="redraw_plots();"` to the Plots tab, but function is called too fast before tab is activated. Any way to get an event when this tab activates?

Thank you.

Comment: Your question has just made my brain melt...can you try to reclarify please?

Comment: Do you wanna call redraw_plots after your tab selection animation is finished?

Comment: @RogerRussel I want to call  redraw_plots when tab was selected and shown on the screen.

Comment: @sashk I think I get your problem, but please do an exemplo on https://jsfiddle.net , your problem is it is activeting before mdl click event, and you wanna it be trigged after mdl change tabs, is it?

Comment: @RogerRussel Correct. I'll add link to the jsfiddle later...

Comment: @RogerRussel here it is - https://jsfiddle.net/v52z1sed/5/

Comment: @sashk I wrote this [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sym4tq4s/) with some examplos of event that you can try.

Comment: @sashk I add on event listening on your code https://jsfiddle.net/v52z1sed/6/, could you please test it works?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92982/discussion-between-sashk-and-roger-russel).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's happen because element inline event are the first event to be executed.

To Execute after MDL tab event you can do like this:

With Javascript Vanilla:

First add an id on link

```
<a id="#plots-tab" href="#plots-tab" class="mdl-layout__tab is-active"">Plots</a>
```

Second add an event listener

```
document.getElementById("#plots-tab").addEventListener("click", function(){
   redraw(); 
});
```

Or with Jquery:

Add on event listener on element

```
$('a[href="#plots-tab"]').on('click',function(){
   redraw();        
});
```

Comment: Thank you, @RogerRussel!

Answer (score 0):

For me it was not enough to hook to the click event.
A timeout of at least 0 milliseconds was necessary otherwise the content display it will still be set to none (tested on Chrome) and any drawing of your own that requires width calculations might fail. 
Check the attached snippet and verify that without setTimeout, on the click event the tab content display is set to none and not 'block'. MDL must play an animation for smooth transition that cause absolute position drawing issues.

```js
$('.mdl-layout__tab-bar').children().each(function(){
  
  $(this).on('click', function(){
    var timeout = 0;
    var targetContent = this.getAttribute('href');
    
    setTimeout(function(){
      if($(targetContent).css('display') == "block"){
         console.info("tab content is now visible after a timeout of %s millisenconds", timeout);
      }
      else{
      console.warn("increase timeout to make sure that content is visible");
      }
    }, timeout);
    
   
  });
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>

<!-- Simple header with scrollable tabs. -->
<div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">
  <header class="mdl-layout__header">
    <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
      <!-- Title -->
      <span class="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
    </div>
    <!-- Tabs -->
    <div class="mdl-layout__tab-bar mdl-js-ripple-effect">
      <a href="#scroll-tab-1" class="mdl-layout__tab is-active">Tab 1</a>
      <a href="#scroll-tab-2" class="mdl-layout__tab">Tab 2</a>
      <a href="#scroll-tab-3" class="mdl-layout__tab">Tab 3</a>
      <a href="#scroll-tab-4" class="mdl-layout__tab">Tab 4</a>
      <a href="#scroll-tab-5" class="mdl-layout__tab">Tab 5</a>
      <a href="#scroll-tab-6" class="mdl-layout__tab">Tab 6</a>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
    <span class="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
  </div>
  <main class="mdl-layout__content">
    <section class="mdl-layout__tab-panel is-active" id="scroll-tab-1">
      <div class="page-content">
        Tab 1
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="mdl-layout__tab-panel" id="scroll-tab-2">
      <div class="page-content">
      Tab 2
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="mdl-layout__tab-panel" id="scroll-tab-3">
      <div class="page-content">
      Tab 3
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="mdl-layout__tab-panel" id="scroll-tab-4">
      <div class="page-content">
      Tab 4
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="mdl-layout__tab-panel" id="scroll-tab-5">
      <div class="page-content">
      Tab 5
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="mdl-layout__tab-panel" id="scroll-tab-6">
      <div class="page-content">
      Tab 6
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried out with Google Chrome Versão 71.0.3578.98 ( Officia Versionl) 64 bits, but the timeout was not necessary, may I ask you which version of Chrome was used on your test?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution without adding anything special to the a tags would be

```
$("a.mdl-layout__tab").click(event => {
    console.log("Tab switched!");
});
```