# "Tab Rendered" event for MDL Tabs

Tags: javascript, material-design-lite

I'm using the MDL tab component. After a tab is clicked and it displays the content for that tab, I'd like to set the cursor focus in a certain text input within that tab's content.

My initial approach was just to handle the click event of the tab element and then set focus accordingly. The problem I'm having is that calling .focus() on the text input element isn't working because it tries to set focus before the text element is actually visible, which no browser seems to like doing for you. If I set focus inside a setTimeout() delay it works, but that doesn't feel like a very clean way to go about it.

Is there any kind of event that can be handled for when a tab is clicked and has finished displaying it's contents? I've also looked at using mutation observers to detect when the text input element is visible but browser support for those is fairly limited still.

Comment: I find tartinesKiller interesting. In case you use timeout as Christian Steinmann suggests, you find a snippet of code in this thread. Notes, that even a timeout of 0 milliseconds is enough to have the tab content visible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33245938/call-a-function-when-tab-selected-in-material-design-light/41854830#41854830

Answer (score 0):

No there is no such option. I think you have to use setTimeout or setInterval

You can look into the source. Perhaps write your own MaterialTabs constructor and register it.

[Material-Design-Lite source, MaterialTab](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/blob/v1.0.6/material.js#L2697)

I think there are also some libs that can do this like jQuery. You can also see

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

This works only in modern browser but has a legacy implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I've added this line :
`window.dispatchEvent(new Event("tabSelected"));`
to the material.js file, at the end of the `selectTab()` function. This way, the event is fired right after the tab content is shown.